# How to link asp.net application with crystalreport while using sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have created a crystal report file using the crystal report software from SAP (http://www.crystalreports.com/). Here I have created 3 parameters that will need to be filled out in order to retreat the rest of information in regards to the specific values in order to auto fill the rest of the form. 
The data base which I am using is in SQL and I would like to know if its possible to make it some how in my ASP.net C# application to push a button from my gridview which is linked to the same database in SQL and automatically pick up the parameters from the gridview and import them into the crystal report so the user wouldn't have to type them in. 
I would imagine that this is just some extra C# programming but I am fairly new to ASP so I would appreciate any feed back or solution on how I can accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.

More Detail:
I have an existing SQL database and a ASP application. My application has two existing grid views and login functions. I also have an existing crystal report designed to automatically  create a receipt from my SQL database. This is done by the user filling out 3 specific parameters and the rest of the data which are in parallel with those parameters will automatically fill out the crystal report.

What I want to do:
I want to create a print button in my gridview to automatically fill out the 3 parameters in crystal report. This is an attempt to make my application more user friendly. In short, the user would push the print button with in its new column in gridview and the 3 parameters are automatically picked up and filled into the crystal report.

Comment: I added more details in the explaining area for you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This link describes how to work with crystal reports on ASP.net, it should answer your question:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/crystal-reports-sample-in-aspnet.html

Below is what your config file looks like connecting to your SQL database.

Web.config

```
<add name="ProjectASPConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PWOEM01;Initial Catalog=ProjectASP;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

PWOEM01= server
ProjectASP = Database

If you need more code examples, let me know what your looking for.

Comment: Hi Michael, I already know how to setup my web.config to connect to my database as it is already connected and the link you posted talks about bringing crystal report in asp view. I have an existing ASP project and it is already running and connecting with my sql database just fine. Iam trying to make one of my gridview which is already running query from my sql database to have an additional column labelled print so when i hit it it automatically picks up 3 of the fields in its row and autofill those values into my crystal report parameters.

Comment: my crystal report is connected and works just fine with my sql but iam trying to make it so the user doesnt have to fill out the parameters to pull a specific data but instead have it automatically populate the fields straight from my application by the user simply clicking on the print button that i want to add in my gridview.